# How do I install virtualbox to my USB

Tags: software-installation, usb, virtualbox

I need to install virtualbox to my USB, if it's possible to make USB memory appear as if it's on my actual computer that would also work

Comment: I created a Full install bootable USB and installed VBox on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you mount the USB memory you can create your virtual disk on it.